# How to get a GUI graph in matplotlib Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, matplotlib

I have this code:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [100, 200, 300, 400]

plot = pyplot.plot(a, b)
```

Trying

```
print(plot)
```

only gives me `[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x112d4b310>]`, which is absolutely ugly and useless. How can I see a *graph* of `plot`? Like a picture or something.
Thank you!

Comment: type `pyplot.show()` to get image of the plot. ;) Most common way of importing is `import mathplotlib.pyplot as plt` it's just what most of the people in the community use.

Comment: OMG that's awesome thx!

Comment: Glad it was useful. ;)